# Pandas read csv file with float values results in weird rounding and decimal digits

Tags: python, pandas, csv, floating-point, rounding

I have a csv file containing numerical values such as `1524.449677`. There are always exactly 6 decimal places.

When I import the csv file (and other columns) via pandas `read_csv`, the column automatically gets the datatype `object`. My issue is that the values are shown as `2470.6911370000003` which actually should be `2470.691137`. Or the value `2484.30691` is shown as `2484.3069100000002`.

This seems to be a datatype issue in some way. I tried to explicitly provide the data type when importing via `read_csv` by giving the `dtype` argument as `{'columnname': np.float64}`. Still the issue did not go away.

How can I get the values imported and shown exactly as they are in the source csv file?

Comment: What about doing `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(float)`?

Comment: does not change anything

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Pandas uses a dedicated `dec 2 bin` converter that compromises accuracy in preference to speed.

Passing `float_precision='round_trip'` to `read_csv` fixes this.

Check out [this page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#specifying-method-for-floating-point-conversion) for more detail on this.

After processing your data, if you want to save it back in a *csv* file, you can pass
`float_format = "%.nf"` to the corresponding method.

A full example:

```
import pandas as pd

df_in  = pd.read_csv(source_file, float_precision='round_trip')
df_out = ... # some processing of df_in
df_out.to_csv(target_file, float_format="%.3f") # for 3 decimal places
```

Comment: float_precision='round_trip' crashed for some reason (errors hidden in PyQt and I didn't spend a lot of time trying to catch them), but float_precision='high' took care of the issue I had. Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason it adds extra decimal digits to some values using `pd.read_csv()` without specifying `float_precision`? While some values keep their decimal places without adding extra.

Comment: @Echan This might be of some help? https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/pandas-floating-point-error.999596/

Answer (score 22):

I realise this is an old question, but maybe this will help someone else:

I had a similar problem, but couldn't quite use the same solution. Unfortunately the `float_precision` option only exists when using the C engine and not with the python engine. So if you have to use the python engine for some other reason (for example because the C engine can't deal with regex literals as deliminators), this little "trick" worked for me:

In the `pd.read_csv` arguments, define `dtype='str'` and then convert your dataframe to whatever dtype you want, e.g. `df = df.astype('float64')` .

Bit of a hack, but it seems to work. If anyone has any suggestions on how to solve this in a better way, let me know.