# How to read_csv float value with correct decimal value in python using

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a .dat file which has float value like `"-1.752"`, when i read this value using `read_csv` I am getting `"-1.7519999999999998"` value.

Not sure how to fix this extra decimal values.

Below is the code i used  it: 
`SOU2PD=pd.read_csv(file_loc+file_name+".dat", sep='\x01',header=None,engine='python',dtype={5 : float,9:float,11:float}).`

Please suggest me.

Comment: You can look into this question.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368296/pandas-read-csv-file-with-float-values-results-in-weird-rounding-and-decimal-dig

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of a Q&A which has a solution. But if it doesn't help, please specify *in your question* exactly what you have tried and, if possible, provide example data which exhibits the problem.

Comment: jpp, i tried the solution given in the above link. when i tried the option float_precision='round_trip', i am getting the error message "The 'float_precision' option is not supported with the 'python' engine"