# Pandas - compare loaded data to processed data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, compare, rounding

I'm writing a unit-test that should compare a saved CSV known results with processed results. My test failed although the result data were equal. My guess was that Panndas rounds the value in some way, so I've created the following snippet to test my speculation:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':[-0.41676538151302184]})
df.to_csv('tmp.csv',index=False)
# Load the saved CSV and compare it
df2 = pd.read_csv('./tmp.csv')
df2.val.compare(df.val)
```

---

```
       self     other
0 -0.416765 -0.416765
```

Pandas shows the differences, although values appear to be equal. If I round the values, comparison successes.

What would be the right way to compare saved data to the calculated one?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368296/pandas-read-csv-file-with-float-values-results-in-weird-rounding-and-decimal-dig) help?

Comment: Yes thanks, alot ,float_precision='round_trip' is a good solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with floating point numbers is precision. As you guessed, your numbers are very close but not exactly identical:

```
df.iloc[0,0]
-0.41676538151302184

df2.iloc[0,0]
-0.4167653815130218
```

```
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:.20f}'.format):
    display(df2.val.compare(df.val))

                     self                   other
0 -0.41676538151302178203 -0.41676538151302183755
```

One option is to use [`numpy.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) or [`numpy.allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html#numpy.allclose), that are specifically designed to test close numbers. There are two parameters `rtol` and `atol` to specify a custom relative or absolute tolerance.

```
import numpy as np
np.isclose(df, df2).all()

# or 
np.allclose(df, df2)
```

output: `True`

Comment: Using `pd.read_csv(..., float_precision='round_trip')` keeps the last decimal if the precision is required.

Comment: Can you add `with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:.20f}'.format): display(df2.val.compare(df.val))`? (and congrats for your 40k)